# Should it be "There is an array of tools" or "There are an array of tools"? Is "array" singular of plural here?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

I’m struggling to understand what the correct wording should be here:

- There **is** a wide array of learning-based image generation tools.

Why is the author using *is*?

The sentence is referring to *tools*. Shouldn’t its verb therefore be plural to match *tools*?

When I put this sentence into some grammar-correction website, it corrects it to:

- There **are** a wide array of learning-based image generation tools.

But the Grammarly website does not complain.

What then is the correct usage, and why? Could both be right? Who decides this?

- https://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/#text=There%2520is%2520a%2520wide%2520array%2520of%2520learning%2520based%2520program%2520repair%2520tools.

Comment: But _array_ is singular.

Comment: An array is a systematic arrangement of similar objects, usually in rows and columns.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array

Comment: Perhaps it varies by dialect; e.g. "The company is," singular, in USA and "The company are," plural, in UK. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=array+is%2Carray+are&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carray%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carray%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Huh?  Nobody says "The company are".  And the ngram is exactly what you expect from a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a wide array of learning-based image generation tools.

I would call this sentence grammatically valid and natural. A fluent speaker might well say or write this. An array can be, and often is, a single object, composed of many parts, just as a collection can be. I would never say "an array are" but always "an array is".

The definition quoted by  user Harrier Panels is only one sense of the word "array". An array need not always consist of **similar** objects, and it need not be aranged ion rows ansd columns, aslthough often it is. But in the use "*a wide array of tools*" (or indeed of anything) the word "array" has essentially the same meaning as "range" or "set". Either of those could be substituted here without changing the meaning.

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/array) gives as the first definition of "array" A  noun:

? an imposing group : large number *faced a whole array of problems* also : variety, assortment /a broad array of styles*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/array) gives:

> a large group of things or people, especially one that is attractive or causes admiration or has been positioned in a particular way:
>
> - *There was a splendid array of food on the table.*
> - *They sat before an array of microphones and cameras.*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/array) statews:

> An array of different things or people is a large number or wide range of them.
> *As the deadline approached she experienced a bewildering array of emotions.*

Note that all of these use array as a **singular** noun, amd none of them mentions rows and columns (although other senses do).

Comment: Nicely explained!

Answer (score 0):

There **is** an array of tools.

'Array' is usually singular. **Is** is appropriate here.

There *is* a wide array of learning-based image generation tools. ('Is' has been used with 'array', NOT with 'tools')

There *are* learning-based image generation tools. ('Are' has been used with 'tools')